# Python Regex: How to just get just the match returned, n times it is found?

Tags: python, regex

How can I just return my desired output: `PASS` (whatever follows after `Result:`) when using `re.findall`?

Consider this partially working example:

```
import re

# string with colored text
s1 = 'Result: [92mPASS[0m     Result: [92mPASS[0m  Result: [92mPASS[0m'

# remove colors and the like
cleaned = re.sub('\x1b\\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z]', '', s1)

# now just look for the result after Result: and return each instance
re.findall(r'Result: ([A-Za-z +:]+)', cleaned)
# ['PASS     Result: PASS  Result: PASS']
```

Comment: Maybe just `re.findall(r'Result:\s*(\w+)', cleaned)`?

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be sufficient!